# entreprise intranet Liferay or Alfresco

Tags: liferay, alfresco, intranet

I want to create an enterprise intranet , that provides authentication of employees and management profiles, messaging, calendar, document management...

I think I can use php or java CMS , for the moment after some research I decided to use Liferay or Alfresco. The problem is that I don't really  know the difference between them , and what I have to choose .

Answer (score 10):

They're quite different products, solving different business needs.

**Liferay**

It's a [Java Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Portlet_specification). It focuses on creating web sites that are able to integrate data coming from different sources and applications in the same page. Using [portlets](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+portlets), you compose a page to enrich it with such mini applications. It's mostly used to create web sites that aggregate information and contain interactive features such as online chat, [blogs](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Blogs+Portlet) and the like. It also provides document management as part of its features, with the possibility of [integrating Alfresco](http://www.cignex.com/articles/integrated-content-management-portal-based-alfresco-liferay) as a backend.

**Alfresco**

It's an [Enterprise Content Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_content_management) system. It revolves around documents, their lifecycle and collaboration capabilities over such documents. With the advent of [Share](http://www.alfresco.com/products/collaboration/), Alfresco now offers a lightweight portal-like application that lets you place "dashlets" in both an User Dashboard and a Site Dashboard (sites are shared workspaces).
While you can have non-document centric [dashlets](http://code.google.com/p/share-extras/), [blogs](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Share_Enterprise_3.0_Features#Site_Component_-_Blog) and [wikis](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Share_Enterprise_3.0_Features#Site_Component_-_Wiki), they're not extremely sophisticated, and most of Alfresco features focus on document management and online collaboration.

Answer (score 3):

I have not worked with portals for quite a while, but I guess the answer is : It really depends. :)

Seriously, in your requirements context I would compare Alfresco Share with Liferay. Both compose pages in a similiar fashion with Webscripts/Portlets components and have security baked in.

I think the most important factor to consider is your skill set.

If you feel at home with Java, the Portlet spec and server side logic : Lean towards Liferay. Alfresco Share/Spring Surf should serve you better if you prefer Javascript in the browser and JSON/REST style programming.

Besides, validate how strong your document management requirements are.

Do you really need super sophisticated search, workflow, versioning, security and the like ?

Sophistication increases complexity. That is also why I would be careful before introducing them both at the same time.

Another point to have in mind may be documentation - guess this point goes to Liferay.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay's primary strength is as a portal where you use existing "applications" to fit your need, or create your own using the Portlet spec. Alfresco is a CMS, so it focuses on content management.

Why not use [both](http://www.alfresco.com/products/integrations/liferay/)?